# Конфигурирование фреймворка Flask (Python), как, например, в Zend Framework, Symfony ...

Tags: flask, python

Приветствую.

Во Flask привязка к приложению контроллеров, обработчиков событий и т. п. принято делать непосредственно в модулях, но вот захотелось вынести эти действия во внешний файл или в питоновский словарь. Например, вот так бы это выглядело (Yaml):

```
# это секция для настройки контроллеров
view: [
  {
    # это мы указываем вызываемый объект (например функцию index)
    action: application.view.index,
    # а тут шаблоны url`ов при совпадении с которыми вызывается функция index
    route: [/, /index]
  }
],
```

Аналогичное привычным способом выглядело бы так:

```
# application.view.index

from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World'
```

Преимущество в том, что теперь мы можем, не залезая во внутрь исходников, подменять обработчики, контроллеры и т. д. Но... вопрос в том, как такой подход соотносится с философией самого Flask, и вообще здоровая ли это идея, были ли еще у кого-нибудь при работе с этим фреймворком такие потребности?

Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то я скажу тебе так, если данный метод не просто приемлем для тебя, а необходим, то простого описания в документации к проекту будет достаточно, чтобы избежать каких-либо непоняток.

Comment: Ну счет необходимости пока не могу сказать, но что так будет значительно удобнее, могу сказать наверняка, главное чтобы это не усложнило понимание взаимодействия модулей в будущем

Comment: Все эти философии чаще всего являются просто рекомендациями и если где-то нет четких, прописанных как pep, правил, требующих неукоснительного соблюдения, то ими в принципе можно пренебречь. Достаточно просто описать в доке, что "так-то так-то, данная структура на мой взгляд кажется более здоровой и правильной в данном проекте" и никто вам ничего не скажет скорее всего.

Если коротко, то да, вы вольны делать все что захотите, вы разработчик! И только вы знаете как лучше будет для результирующего продукта.

Answer (score 0):

В документации [здесь](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) и [здесь](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#url-route-registrations) об этом расскаызвается.

Есть методы, которые могут в этом помочь:

```
 add_url_rule(rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options)
```

который работает как стандартный декоратор:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

что эквивалентно

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

Если `view_func` не указана, то так:

```
app.view_functions['index'] = index
```

С `request.method`, соответственно так:

```
def index():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # custom options handling here
        ...
    return 'Hello World!'
index.provide_automatic_options = False
index.methods = ['GET', 'OPTIONS']

app.add_url_rule('/', index)
```

Если я Вас правильно понял, то это то, что Вам нужно. При генерации словаря, можно автоматически импортировать эксншы.

Вот так я автоматически импортирую `Blueprints`:

```
def create_app():
    ...
    register_routes(app)
    ...
    return app


def register_routes(app):
    """Register routes."""
    from . import controllers
    from flask.blueprints import Blueprint

    for module in _import_submodules_from_package(controllers):
        bp = getattr(module, 'bp')
        if bp and isinstance(bp, Blueprint):
            app.register_blueprint(bp)



def _import_submodules_from_package(package):
    import pkgutil

    modules = []
    for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__,
                                                         prefix=package.__name__ + "."):
        modules.append(__import__(modname, fromlist="dummy"))
    return modules
```

А уже в самих `Blueprints` можно реализовывать те самые экшны.

Так же, возможно, пригодится такой хелпер:

```
rules = {}
for endpoint, _rules in iteritems(app.url_map._rules_by_endpoint):
    if any(item in endpoint for item in ['_debug_toolbar', 'debugtoolbar', 'static', 'admin']):
        continue
    rules[endpoint] = [{'rule': rule.rule} for rule in _rules]
```

Который позволяет легко получить урлы для последующего маппинга, с обходом `debugtoolbar`, `admin` и пр. , к примеру, для последующей генерации sitemap.

Или вот такая команда, для `manage.py`, чтобы всегда можно было оперативно просмотреть, какие урлы сейчас зарегистрированы:

```
@manager.command
def list_routes():
    import urllib.request
    from flask import url_for
    output = []
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        options = {}
        for arg in rule.arguments:
            options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)

        methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
        url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
        line = urllib.request.unquote("{:50s} {:20s} {}".format(rule.endpoint, methods, url))


    for line in sorted(output):
        print (line)
```